# How can I get colour emois on the web

Tags: css, emoji

‍♂️                                           ❤️

I am trying to replace a web based emoticon system based on a series of gif images that I implemented around 2008 sort of time with characters from the unicode set. The list of emojis that I display above is my choice of icons to replace the equivalent emoticon set I was using.  Not perfect, but close enough.

Except that they are not in colour!

When I paste them , as I pasted them here into gedit, gedit displays them all in colour.  However even though I took the font that I think gedit is using (Dejavu Sans Mono) loaded it into a web page using `@font-face` there are displays, as here in mostly black and white, with just a couple in colour. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is part of my css

```
   .item {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family:'DejaVu Sans Mono', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    scroll-snap-align:start;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    margin:0 5px 5px 3px;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Sans Mono';
    src: url('/fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works on my Chrome Desktop browser, my Android Phone and my Apple Ipad.

I downloaded this font
https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/blob/master/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf

Put it in my `/fonts` directory where the web server could find it.

and then used the following in my CSS

```css
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'NotoColorEmoji';
        src: url('/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: swap;
      }
```

and

```css
      .item {
        height: 60px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        font-family:'NotoColorEmoji', 'Roboto', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        scroll-snap-align:start;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
        margin:0 5px 5px 3px;
      }
```

Now all my chosen emoji are in color.